# Is my email shared or not shared on npmjs?

Tags: javascript, npm

I have created an account for `npmjs`. There is a `Public Email` field. I wrote my email but i have a question: Is my email shared? I looked to my settings and it says "This email will be added to the metadata of packages you publish". Can other people see my email?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes,** other people will be able to see the public email address you used to sign up with when you created your account. However, your email address isn't directly shared but anyone who downloads your package will be able to see your public email address due to it being stored within your package's metadata.

Directly from npm's documentation:

Your public email address will be added to the metadata of your packages and will be **visible to anyone who downloads** your packages.We will also send email to this account when you update packages, as well as occasional product updates and information. For more information check out npm's [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-new-npm-user-account).

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: I do wonder why... I find this highly discouraging. Others have no business with my e-mail address.